# How do I display all WooCommerce notices so I can theme them

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

Is there a way to test all possible notices that can appear in a WooCommerce store, so I can check they look OK?

As an alternative to stumbling around in the site trying to get messages to appear...

- *Product X has been added to your cart*
- *Product X removed. Undo?*
- etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can't list all WooCommerce notices (and it will not be useful as some 3rd party plugins add their own ones).

But there is 3 type of notices used on WooCommerce on Front end.

They all use a different template type located in [`woocommerce/templates/notices/`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/3.7.0/templates/notices) to be rendered. For each the html structure is as follow:

- [Success message](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.7.0/templates/notices/success.php) type: `<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">A success message…</div>`
- [Notice message](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.7.0/templates/notices/notice.php) type: `<div class="woocommerce-info">A notice message…</div>`
- [Error message](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.7.0/templates/notices/error.php) type: `<div class="woocommerce-error" role="alert">An error message…</div>`

Some of them can have additional html, like `<strong>`, `<em>`, `<a>`… with specific tag classes.

Some third party plugins can add their own additional html.